# Inserting Datetime into Predefined 15min Intervals

Tags: sql, datetime, intervals

I have a table with Datetime value and outbound call numbers. I need to be able to round the datetime down to the lower 15min interval, which is fine when I use DATEADD(mi,DATEDIFF(mi,0,[callplacedtime])/15*15, 0).

What I need to do now is for eg. if my search parameter is between 08:00:00 to 20:00:00 then I need to see '0' for the intervals where there were no data.

At the moment if there are not records in a specific interval then it doesn't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble you're having is because there's no call numbers with datetimes within that range, SQL doesn't know that those datetimes exist or need to be shown.

Try using a [numbers table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) to generate all the 15-minute offset times for the day, and then do a LEFT join from those 15-minute values to your current dataset. This means that all the times will exist, but if there are no call numbers for that 15-minute block, you'll get a NULL to interpret as you please.

Comment: Thanks, That actually makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SQL, but you could have an If/ElseIf/Else statement along the lines of:

```
If second = 0 then displaysecond = "00"
Elseif 0 < second < 10 then displaysecond = "0" + second
Else displaysecond = second
```